# Elasticsearch adding custom analyzer to all fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I created a custom analyzer(See Below)

```
    "analyzer":{
        "custom-analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
    }
```

Now i want to add this analyzer for ALL fields in my mappings, I know I can add to each field like this

```
"test_field":{
      "type": "text,
       ...
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
 }
```

This works perfectly but  I have like 50 fields so I dont want to go and add this analyzer line in each field in my mappings, I was wondering if there is a way too add this for ALL fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the index settings, define an analyzer named [`default`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html) which defines the analyzer when a field mapping does not define an analyzer.

```
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "default": {
        "type": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```